# JavaScript/HTML: Why does the result not show?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trouble when I click the Calculate button it doesn't show anything in field of the result. How can I solve this problem?

```js
    window.onload = function toBmr() {
    var gender = document.getElementById('gender');
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight');
    var height = document.getElementById('height');
    var age = document.getElementById('age');
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    var calculate = document.getElementById('calculate');
    calculate.addEventListener('click', toCalculate);

        function toCalculate() {
            if(gender.value && weight.value && height.value && age.value) {
                if(gender.value === 1) {
                    result.value = 66.47 + (13.7 * weight.value) + (5.003 * height.value) - (6.755 * age.value);
                    return result.toFixed(2);
                } 
                if(gender.value === 2) {
                    result.value = 655.1 + (9.563 * weight.value) + (1.85 * height.value) - (4.676 * age.value);
                    return result.toFixed(2);
                }
            }
            if(!gender.value || !weight.value || !height.value || !age.value) {
                result.value = " ";
            }
        };
    };
```

```html
<form name="do-form">
<p>BMR Calculator</p>
<p>Gender:
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male">Male
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female">Female
</p>
<p>Weight:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" size="10" maxlength="6" onkeyup="fieldCheck">&nbsp;kg</p>
<p>Height:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="height" id="height" size="10" maxlength="6" onkeyup="fieldCheck">&nbsp;cm</p>
<p>Age:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="age" id="age" size="10" maxlength="3" onkeyup="fieldCheck"></p>
<input type="submit" id="calculate" value="Calculate" alt="calculate" onclick="toCalculate()">
<input type="submit" id="clear" value="Clear" alt="clear"><br><br>
<label>BMR = &nbsp;<input id="result" type="text" name="result"  size="15" maxlength="10" />&nbsp;calories/day</label> 
</form>
```

Any help will be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: You probably want to avoid using `type="submit"` for your buttons, they cause the page to navigate to itself, essentially resetting everything on the page.  Use `type="button"`

Comment: 1) You are not getting the value from elements; 2) You are not putting the result to the result field; 3) `id` of element on the page should be unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to use `button` instead of `<input type="submit>` in your form so that the page does not refresh.
2. Your gender radio values are `male` and `female` and you are checking if they are `1` and `2` in your script.
3. `result.toFixed` is not a function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="do-form">
<p>BMR Calculator</p>
<p>Gender:
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male">Male
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female">Female
</p>
<p>Weight:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" size="10" maxlength="6">&nbsp;kg</p>
<p>Height:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="height" id="height" size="10" maxlength="6">&nbsp;cm</p>
<p>Age:&nbsp;<input type="number" name="age" id="age" size="10" maxlength="3"></p>
<button type="button" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
<button type="button" id="clear" alt="clear">Clear</button><br><br>
<label>BMR = &nbsp;<input id="result" type="text" name="result"  size="15" maxlength="10" />&nbsp;calories/day</label>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
window.onload = function toBmr() {
var gender = document.getElementById('gender');
var weight = document.getElementById('weight');
var height = document.getElementById('height');
var age = document.getElementById('age');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var calculate = document.getElementById('calculate');
calculate.addEventListener('click', toCalculate);

    function toCalculate() {
        if(gender.value && weight.value && height.value && age.value) {
            if(gender.value == 'male') {
                result.value = 66.47 + (13.7 * weight.value) + (5.003 * height.value) - (6.755 * age.value);
            } 
            if(gender.value == 'female') {
                result.value = 655.1 + (9.563 * weight.value) + (1.85 * height.value) - (4.676 * age.value);
            }
        }
        if(!gender.value || !weight.value || !height.value || !age.value) {
            result.value = " ";
        }
    };
};
```